# How to revoke Azure's Shared Access Signature (SAS) with nodejs, after finished file upload?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I was able to generate SAS token with

```js
import { generateBlobSASQueryParameters } from '@azure/storage-blob';

function generateUploadUrl(){
    const startsOn = new Date();
    const expiresOn =  new Date(startsOn.valueOf() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const userDelegationKey = await this.blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(startsOn, expiresOn);

    const queryParams = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({    // HERE
        containerName
        permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse('racwd'),
        startsOn,
        expiresOn,
    }, userDelegationKey, this.storageAccount);

    const token = queryParams.toString();
    return `https://${this.storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/${this.containerName}/?${token}`;
}
```

and thanks to that I was able to upload file with this link:

```js
import { ContainerClient } from '@azure/storage-blob';

function uploadFile(localFilePath: string){
    const containerClient = new ContainerClient(generatedUrl);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath);
}
```

Now, after upload of file will finish, **I want to revoke SAS token**, to not allow further uploads to blob. **How I can do this?** I was not able to find any examples/information about that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly revoke a SAS token. But you can revoke the user delegation key, which will invalidate ALL tokens signed with it.

I don't see a .NET method for this actually, but you can do it with [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/revoke-user-delegation-keys), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/revoke-azstorageaccountuserdelegationkeys?view=azps-6.6.0) or [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_account_revoke_delegation_keys).